# Configuring TestFlight for Multiple APK

Tags: android, jenkins, testflight

I use MAVEN profiles to build different versions of my Android application. Now all versions of the app has the same manifest version. I generate 5 possible APK's. Is it possible to distribute all 5 through to test flight.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

TestFlight will allow you to upload different builds of the same version, so long as there are differences in class files. However you would need to generate them with different package names if you want them to look like different apps and allow parallel installs on the same device.

Comment: Would TestFlight allow me to upload a apk with same version and same package to a different teams.